# Using server variables in .htaccess error text

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

Is there a way in .htaccess to use `%{REQUEST_URI}` in the `ErrorDocument` thingy? Because I can't redirect using `ErrorDocument` and I want the url to stay the same (in the url bar like `example.com/thispagedoesnotexist` instead of `example.com/404`).

Because everyone nowadays uses `ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404`
(or similar) and in the /404 file they use something like `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

But my host does not allow that so I have to use "plain" text error messages
`ErrorDocument 404 "<h1>The requested page could not be found.</h1>"`

So I thought I could use server variables to represent the PHP code, but I can't get it to work, or is it not possible?
Because `ErrorDocument 404 "<h1>The requested page %{REQUEST_URI} could not be found.</h1>"` does not work.

### Update:

---

My .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes 

RewriteRule ^admin/login$ /admin/user/userLogin.php
RewriteRule ^admin/logout$ /admin/user/userLogout.php

# this works \/
ErrorDocument 404 "<h1>Page not found</h1>"
# and this throws an 500
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The 500 error looks like this

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and  
was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mydomain.com and
inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might 
have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: don't put your error html in .htaccess, there are plenty of other ways. if host disable some, there are others, check your hosting control panel, if its cPanel it is right there. Email hosting for support.

Comment: There isn't cPanel or such kind of control panel and support doesn't know anything about these kinds of question because they just google and can't find anything on the first page.

Comment: Short answer : No, you cant use %{REQUEST_URI} in error document, because it is part of a diffrent module.

Comment: @starkeen thanks for the information, I'll search for other method then.

Comment: @tomudding - what happens if you were to change it to `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php`, where `error.php` is the file that outputs the error message? Does it give you an error?

Comment: @MikeRockett it throws an 500 on server level (even if I set `ErrorDocument 500 "some text"` it throws the server 500)

Comment: And if you remove the line, does the error go away? I don't think that `ErrorDocument` can be forced to disallow files. So something must be wrong with your configuration. If you update your question with the contents of your `.htaccess` file, we may be able to find the problem.

Comment: @MikeRockett yes, if the line is removed the error goes away, I'm very sure my other lines are working perfect because they all work.

Comment: Are you able to access your server error logs? And what is the exact 500 message you receive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105485/discussion-between-tomudding-and-mike-rockett).